# Does R kernel in Jupyter use iPython notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Does R kernel in Jupyter use iPython notebook? Or some form of knitr/ rmd?

Comment: iPython notebook has been rebranded as JuPyteR to reflect the fact that it supports Julia, Python, R and others. Jupyter = iPython. The kernel basically runs the R REPL in the background. You can run it with lots of other programs (Octave for one example) with the Jupyter notebook just providing an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter which kernel you use (Python, R, etc.), Jupyter uses its own open source notebook format that is JSON-based. It does not use `knitr` or R Markdown.

https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/